# Why is execution time of restful web service on calling sequentially after 1 sec with the same URL query decreasing?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, tomcat8

I have created a restful web service using Jersy on application server tomcat v 8.0 and i call web service after every  1 sec

Here is my restful web service:-

```
@Path("/db")
public class UserLoginDBRst2 
{
DBConnection2 dbCoN;
Connection conn;
ResultSet rslt;
String Iuser="Invalid User";
public static double visitplace2;
@Path("/{latitude}/{longitude}")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public String LogicUserValidation(@PathParam ("latitude")String lat,@PathParam ("longitude")String longt) throws SQLException 
{
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    visitplace2=visitplace2+1;
    String lLoginQuery="Select * from place_giver_table where latitude="+ lat + " and longitude="+longt;

    dbCoN=new DBConnection2();

    try{
        conn=DBConnection2.setDBConnection();
        rslt=dbCoN.getResultSet(lLoginQuery,conn);

        if(rslt.next())
        {
            String name=rslt.getString(4);

            long stopTime = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println(stopTime - startTime);
            return  name + visitplace2;
        }
        else
        {

            long stopTime = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println(stopTime - startTime);
            return Iuser + visitplace2;
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    finally
    {
        if(conn!=null)
        {

            conn.close();
        }

    }

    long stopTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(stopTime - startTime);
    return Iuser + visitplace2;
    }
}
```

Response time log:-

```
0.221560417
0.017982066
0.017500935
0.024799183
0.016682356
0.020753906
.
.
.
.
0.005201366
0.005475563
0.005381554
0.005084748
0.005325283
0.005599511
```

I guess there is some problem with the cache memory which is storing some values
after being called with same url again and again in that case i am attaching my context.xml as well

here is META-INF\context.xml:-

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
</Context>
```

Hope to get help on this

Thanks in advance !

Comment: At least the first drop in response time should come from your db's cache warming up. That's neither tomcat nor webservice related.

Comment: So how to remove db's cache as well , all in all i need no cache coz what i am doing is testing of a web service on application server ?

Comment: That depends on your db and i'm in doubt if that's possible at all. But if you are testing your service: Why not just mocking away the db?

Comment: No, i can't mock DB coz i want the execution time which includes fetching data everytime from the DB when a web services is called .

Comment: Excuse me, but that's a bit strange: In production, you should always have your caches warmed up so what is the reason you want to test/measure the warm up phase? If you really want to do that then the only possibility i can see is a restart of your db before each test. Can you give more information about your use case?

Comment: Okay , agreed taking warm up phase is not into my consideration .I have a point will this sql query help in dumping the cache "SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_dump_now=ON;" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for trouble ,I agree with Dirk Lachowski that the time is decreasing because of caching , as the web services warm up then only it is advisable to take readings.